# Determining which flags are missing from enum

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say i have the enum below:

```
[Flags]
public enum NotifyType
{

    None = 0,
    Window = 1 << 0,
    Sound = 1 << 1,
    Flash = 1 << 2,
    MobileSound = 1 << 3,
    MobilePush = 1 << 4
}
```

Considering two enums:

```
var myenums = Window | Sound | Flash;


//var possibleUpdate = Window | MobilePush;

void UpdateMyEnums(NotifyType possibleUpdate)
{
    //Does myenums contain all the flags in 'possibleUpdate'?  If not add
    //the missing flags to myenums

}
```

How is it possible to determine that the `myenums` variable does not contain the `NotifyType.MobilePush` value in comparison to the `possibleUpdate`?  Do i have to test each flag in `possibleUpdate` against `myenums`?

I am using C# on .NET 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to figure out which one is missing, you just need to do `bit-wise OR` between `myenums` and `possibleUpdate` and then assign the value back.

```
//Does myenums contain all the flags in 'possibleUpdate'?  
if (myenums & possibleUpdate != possibleUpdate)
    //If not add the missing flags to myenums
    myenums = myenums | possibleUpdate;
```

Comment: You could use |=, but he isn't looking for that.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. He is talking about adding the missing flags and this is exactly what he needs. There is no need to figure out which one is missing.

Comment: He doesn't want to add the missing flags, he wants to **get** the missing flags.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. The code comment says "If not add the missing flags to myenums" and that's exactly what this code does.

Comment: @joel In further inspection that's right, but in a comment to my answer he specifies he also needs the missing flags.

Comment: OK I guess, maybe we should let Mike_G to clarify his question. Since we have been guessing for 10 minutes here. LOL

Comment: Although my question was to 'add' the missing flags, I can see why @It'sNotALie got confused, because in my comment in his post, I said some pretty confusing stuff.

Comment: @Mike_G There's still a way to get the missing flags. It's pretty involved.

Comment: @It'sNotALie Yes, but you have set me on the right path and it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (myenums & possibleUpdate != possibleUpdate)
    //not a possible update
```

To get the flags needed not in `myenums`:

```
NotifyType missing = (~(myenums ^ wanted) ^ wanted) & (myenums | wanted);
```

Comment: Yes, Im sorry @It'sNotALie, my early comment was confusing.  On the bright side, you did answer my next question!  So i upvoted in thanks.

Comment: @Mike_G Do understand it's absolutely horrifying :P

Answer (score 4):

In .NET 4+ you can use (and people will whinge about it being 10x slower than a manual operation, of course) you can use [`Enum.HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx), obviously negating the result.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to simply bitwise-Or the needed flags. If you wanted a sequence of the missing flags, for say reporting:

```
var missing = Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotifyType)).Cast<NotifyType>()
                  .Where(nt => ((nt & possibleUpdate) == nt)
                            && ((nt & myenums) == 0));

Console.WriteLine("Missing: {0}", String.Join(" | ", missing));
```

You can clean this up a bit with `Enum.HasFlag`:

```
var missing = Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotifyType)).Cast<NotifyType>()
                  .Where(nt => possibleUpdate.HasFlag(nt)
                            && !myenums.HasFlag(nt));
```